# Change stackView nested label color programatically when separate image is tapped. Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have an array of "hotspot views" which are just UIImage's and an array of stackviews which contain two labels in each. Im trying to get the color of the hotspot view image and one of the labels to change to red when the hotspot view is tapped. I cant seem to find out how after googling most of the day. Any insight would be great.

Here is my code below:

I have commented out in the tap gesture function what i was hoping to achieve but i have no idea how to access the nested labels in the stackview or if im using the tap gesture recognizer correctly.

```
    import UIKit
    import OAStackView

    protocol StandMapHotspotLayerViewDataSource {

        func numberOfHotspots(standMapHotspotLayerView: StandMapHotspotLayerView) -> Int

        func hotspotViewForIndex(index: Int, inStandMapHotspotLayerView: StandMapHotspotLayerView) -> (UIView, OAStackView)
    }

    struct HotspotDataSource {

        var stackView: [OAStackView] = []
        var hotspotView: [UIView] = []
    }

    class StandMapHotspotLayerView: UIView {

        var dataSource: StandMapHotspotLayerViewDataSource?
        var hotspotDataSource = HotspotDataSource()

        override func layoutSubviews() {
            super.layoutSubviews()

            let hotspotCount = self.dataSource?.numberOfHotspots(self) ?? 0

            (0..<hotspotCount).map({ index in
                return self.dataSource!.hotspotViewForIndex(index, inStandMapHotspotLayerView: self)
            }).forEach({ hotspotView, stackView in

                hotspotDataSource.hotspotView.append(hotspotView)
                hotspotDataSource.stackView.append(stackView)

                hotspotView.userInteractionEnabled = true
                let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: hotspotView, action: #selector(self.hotspotWasPressed(_:)))
                self.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)

                self.addSubview(hotspotView)
                self.addSubview(stackView)
            })

            addLine()
        }

        func hotspotWasPressed(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    //
    //        sender.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    //        
    //        let hotspotView = hotspotDataSource.hotspotView[index]
    //        let stackView = hotspotDataSource.stackView[index]
    //        
    //        hotspotView.tintColor = UIColor(red: 157, green: 27, blue: 50, alpha: 1)
    //        stackView
        }

        func addLine() {
            let path = UIBezierPath()
            let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            for index in 0..<self.dataSource!.numberOfHotspots(self) {
                let stackView = hotspotDataSource.stackView[index]
                let hotspotView = hotspotDataSource.hotspotView[index]
                if stackView.frame.origin.y < 100 {
                    let stackViewPoint = CGPointMake(stackView.frame.origin.x + stackView.frame.size.width / 2, stackView.frame.origin.y + stackView.frame.size.height)
                    let imageViewPoint = CGPointMake((hotspotView.frame.origin.x + hotspotView.frame.size.width / 2), hotspotView.frame.origin.y)
                    path.moveToPoint(stackViewPoint)
                    path.addLineToPoint(imageViewPoint)
                } else {
                    let stackViewPoint = CGPointMake(stackView.frame.origin.x + stackView.frame.size.width / 2, stackView.frame.origin.y)
                    let imageViewPoint = CGPointMake((hotspotView.frame.origin.x + hotspotView.frame.size.width / 2), hotspotView.frame.origin.y + hotspotView.bounds.size.height)
                    path.moveToPoint(stackViewPoint)
                    path.addLineToPoint(imageViewPoint)
                }
                shapeLayer.path = path.CGPath
                shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
                shapeLayer.lineWidth = 0.2
                shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
                self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
            }
        }

        func reloadData() {
            self.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. See code below:

```
    import UIKit
    import OAStackView

    protocol StandMapHotspotLayerViewDataSource {

        func numberOfHotspots(standMapHotspotLayerView: StandMapHotspotLayerView) -> Int

        func hotspotViewForIndex(index: Int, inStandMapHotspotLayerView: StandMapHotspotLayerView) -> (UIImageView, OAStackView)
    }

    struct HotspotViews {

        var stackView: [OAStackView] = []
        var hotspotView: [UIImageView] = []
    }

    class StandMapHotspotLayerView: UIView {

        var dataSource: StandMapHotspotLayerViewDataSource?
        var hotspotViews = HotspotViews()

        override func layoutSubviews() {
            super.layoutSubviews()

            let hotspotCount = self.dataSource?.numberOfHotspots(self) ?? 0

            var i: Int = 0

            (0..<hotspotCount).map({ index in
                return self.dataSource!.hotspotViewForIndex(index, inStandMapHotspotLayerView: self)
            }).forEach({ hotspotView, stackView in

                hotspotViews.hotspotView.append(hotspotView)
                hotspotViews.stackView.append(stackView)

                hotspotView.userInteractionEnabled = true
                hotspotView.tag = i
                let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.hotspotWasPressed(_:)))
                hotspotView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)

                self.addSubview(hotspotView)
                self.addSubview(stackView)

                i += 1
            })

            addLine()
        }

        func hotspotWasPressed(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
            let index = sender.view!.tag
            let hotspot = hotspotViews.hotspotView[index]
            let textLabel = hotspotViews.stackView[index].arrangedSubviews.first as? UILabel

            hotspot.image = UIImage(named: "RedHotspotImage")
            textLabel?.textColor = UIColor(red: 158/255, green: 27/255, blue: 50/255, alpha: 1)


            //go to hotspot url: StandMapView.hotspots[index].url
        }

        func addLine() {
            let path = UIBezierPath()
            let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            for index in 0..<self.dataSource!.numberOfHotspots(self) {
                let stackView = hotspotViews.stackView[index]
                let hotspotView = hotspotViews.hotspotView[index]
                if stackView.frame.origin.y < 100 {
                    let stackViewPoint = CGPointMake(stackView.frame.origin.x + stackView.frame.size.width / 2, stackView.frame.origin.y + stackView.frame.size.height)
                    let imageViewPoint = CGPointMake((hotspotView.frame.origin.x + hotspotView.frame.size.width / 2), hotspotView.frame.origin.y)
                    path.moveToPoint(stackViewPoint)
                    path.addLineToPoint(imageViewPoint)
                } else {
                    let stackViewPoint = CGPointMake(stackView.frame.origin.x + stackView.frame.size.width / 2, stackView.frame.origin.y)
                    let imageViewPoint = CGPointMake((hotspotView.frame.origin.x + hotspotView.frame.size.width / 2), hotspotView.frame.origin.y + hotspotView.bounds.size.height)
                    path.moveToPoint(stackViewPoint)
                    path.addLineToPoint(imageViewPoint)
                }
                shapeLayer.path = path.CGPath
                shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
                shapeLayer.lineWidth = 0.2
                shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
                self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
            }
        }

        func reloadData() {
            self.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
```

Important parts were to pass a .tag through on the hotspot view and then to access the label within the stackview by 
stackView[index].arrangedSubviews.first as? UILabel

thanks